# Looping and Searching Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am looking to search for a specific folder name within all the directories of a root and moving them into a destination folder. I manage to get it to work however the looping will continue till it catches an error. How can I stop the looping once it’s being successfully moved?

```
source = “\\\\ABCSHARE\\2020”
dest = “\\\\STORAGE\\2020”

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
   if “buffet” in dirpath:
      shutil.copytree(dirpath,dest)
```

How can I catch an exception to stop the looping and append any files if there is existing folder in `dest`?

Comment: Just use `break` ? Additionally, have a look into `glob(...)`. And do the folder names really have all these backslashes? Also, it should certainly read `if "buffet" in dirpath` (note the other quotes).

Comment: Just put break in else.

Comment: I did a break just adding else: break. But then nothing would happen if I execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

use **break** to stop the iteration after the move.

you can add a nested if statement to check if a folder already exists in the destination.

Comment: I did a break in my else then nothing happened at all. How can I do it in the nested statements ?

Comment: the break needs to be in the line after the move, not in an else block. just like @Mr Felix U answered.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to break if you have indeed found and moved that tree, not "else".

```py
source = “\\\\ABCSHARE\\2020”
dest = “\\\\STORAGE\\2020”

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
   if “buffet” in dirpath:
      shutil.copytree(dirpath,dest)
      break
```

Comment: Thank you but I had tried this way too. The script didn’t execute somehow once I insert the break